# Determining whether file supports Exif header in Java

Tags: java, exif, metadata-extractor

I am using Java and the library [metadata extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) to work with file metadata.

What I want is to reliably check if a file supports the Exif header (also if it would be supported if it is not available in the header yet).

As far as I know, the Exif header is supported by JPEG and TIFF, and also by some PNGs (among others).

Currently I am just checking the file type for JPEG or TIFF (by using  `FileTypeDetector::detectFileType`), but is it possible to reliably determine whether the file supports the Exif header without checking the file type? Then files of other formats which also support the Exif header could be taken into account, too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would it be a problem attempting to get the exif info and then handling any exceptions/errors accordingly? Presumably your goal is to get the info? Any other way would be (afaics) redundant and will give you a code-maintenance problem over a moving target of changing specs and capabilitites

Comment: Getting the info is not the problem. But I don't just want to get the Exif info but also write something to the Exif header/change the Exif info. If a file doesn't have an Exif header yet (but supports it) I want to create the Exif header and write the info to it. So I cannot just check if an Exif header is already available and read if if so.

Comment: Right. Does that library support writing Exif?

Comment: The `Metadata` class has a method `addDirectory` where I can add new directories (e.g. a new instance of `ExifIFD0Directory`) and on `Directory` you can call `setInt`, `setString` etc. So I assume that the library supports writing Exif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to reliably determine whether the file supports the Exif header without checking the file type?

No. There's no way to "detect" whether a file supports Exif meta data (the term "Exif header" is a misnomer) by inspecting the file. I think your current way of determining the file format, and keep a list of formats you know support Exif makes sense.

---

Note that each file format that supports Exif metadata typically wraps it in a "native" (as in the format's own) container structure, so you typically have to add custom code for each format you want to add Exif metadata to. The only exception is TIFF, as Exif metadata is based on the TIFF format. See also [Wikipedia on Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#Technical).

Of course, it is technically possible to append or insert Exif metadata to *any* file, however, but this will typically render the file corrupt or the Exif metadata will be ignored by other software.

Answer (score 1):

*Exif* is supported by more file formats than you may think, and most software doesn't expect so. Also it may occur more than once, albeit making little sense and not being expected by any reader.

- [JFIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) (JPEG): in an APP1 segment with the prefix `"Exif\0\0"`
- [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), [JNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_Network_Graphics), [MNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics): in text chunks (`iTXt`, `zTXt`, `tEXt`) with the keyword `exif` or `APP1`, or in their own chunks (`eXIf`, `zXIf`, `zxIf`)
- [PSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.psd): in a resource with the ID `0x0422` or `0x0423`
- [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) and many formats borrowing from that ([CR2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), [ORF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), [DNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Negative), [RAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), [JXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XR), [NIFF](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/NIFF_(Navy_Image_File_Format)), [MDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_shared_tools#MDI_file_format)): in the tag `0x8769` (and `0x8825` for GPS and `0xA005` for Interoperability)
- formats using [QTFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) (i.e. [JP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000), [JXS](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/JPEG_XS), [JXL](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/JPEG_XL), [HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format), [QTIF](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/QTIF) pictures or [MOV/QT/3GP/MP4/AVC/MJ2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) containers): in the atoms `exif` or `exfc`, or thru the atom `uuid` with an UUID of either `"\x05\x37\xcd\xab\x9d\x0c\x44\x31\xa7\x2a\xfa\x56\x1f\x2a\x11\x3e"` or one that literally resembles to the 16 bytes `"JpgTiffExif->JP2"`
- formats using [RIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) (i.e. [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) pictures or [AVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) containers or [WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV), [SBK](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/SoundFont_1.0), [SB2](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/SoundFont_2.0), [AIFF/AIFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format), [8SVX](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/8SVX) audio): either an `exif` list with a couple of own chunks, or an `EXIF` chunk

This list might not be complete. And you asked for **Exif** alone - support for **[XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)** is a topic on its own.